# Can the Rinne-Sharingan like Kayuga or Hagoromo had be transplanted?

Tags: naruto

Can the Rinne-Sharingan be transplanted  or can it not because it comes from the forehead? Even if it could be transplanted would it have to be transplanted in the head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rinne-Sharingan is a dōjutsu [kekkei mōra](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kekkei_M%C5%8Dra) (advanced branch of jutsu unique to Kaguya Ōtsutsuki and her direct bloodline). Rinne-Sharingan can't be transplanted onto non-Otsutsuki members, but there are ways to wield it, and the exact instructions are written on the Uchiha stone tablet:

1. You need to have the Rinnegan in both eyes.
2. You need to the Jinchuriki of Ten-Tails.

Madara Uchiha, as the Ten-Tails' Jinchūriki, was able to manifest this dōjutsu in his own forehead after regaining both of his Rinnegan. As a result of Black Zetsu's actions, Madara's body then served as a vessel to resurrect Kaguya.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more on *why* it can't be transplanted to non-Otsutsuki (bit confused)? The fact that a Rinne-Sharingan is in your forehead means you now have an eye socket in your forehead, and an eye is an eye, no matter where located. (thats why im confused)

Comment: @DANIEL Because it is a bloodline dojutsu. It just cannot be transplanted to Non-bloodline members. Just like Uchiha cannot transplant Byakugan and Hyuga cannot transplant Sharingan. It doesn't matter whether Rinne-sharingan is located.

Comment: Ohhhh! I get that. let me upvote now that thats clarified